# IOS Status Bar not in its position

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, statusbar

I working with an application which consist of two Targets (Paid and free). The In free version the status bar was misplaced somewhere in the screen (Both in ios7 and ios 6.1). But the Paid version working perfectly. Any ideas? Refer below image

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have forgotten to add the 4" default-image to your project, the `Default-568h@2x.png`, so your application is in 3.5" mode.

Comment: Yes, this is what i missed here.

Answer (score 2):

set your iPhone retina 4 launch image 640*1136

[image]